# Какие значения @Target правильно использовать для аннотации, которая используется, как свойство другой аннотации?

Tags: java, аннотации

Имеется две аннотации:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE })
public @interface Modified {

public String author();

public String description() default "";

public Date date();
}
```

и

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ ElementType.????????? })
public @interface Date {

public Day day();

public Month month();

public Year year();
}
```

В первой аннотации Date ссылается на вторую аннотацию.
Во второй аннотации Day, Month и Year - это Enum. Вторая будет использоваться только как контейнер для даты в первой аннотации.

**Вопрос:**

Какое значение (или значения) `@Target({ElementType.????????? })` правильно использовать во второй аннотации?

Comment: Ну перечислите все варианты. Жалко что ли этих  ElementType.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Подойдёт пустой список:

```
@Target({})
```

Comment: Да, именно так и сделал. И нашел подтверждение этому в [документации](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Target.html) Oracle:
This meta-annotation indicates that the declared type is intended solely for use as a member type in complex annotation type declarations. It cannot be used to annotate anything directly:
`@Target({}) 
    public @interface MemberType {
        ...
    }`